# Wget: convert links to point to downloaded files (like images)

Tags: linux, wget

Is it possible to convert things like the location of a jpeg image linked to a website to the location found on your hard drive using wget?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-k` argument to rewrite the links in the downloaded files to make them suitable for local viewing:

```
wget -k https://example.com/foo.html
```

More specificly this rewrites links to downloaded web pages, images, style sheets etc.

In many cases you might want to use this with `-r` (recursive).

Comment: what does -r mean?

Comment: "Recursive" - see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) or the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).